# JavaScript Web SQL callbacks insert if not exists

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I am inserting resources into the database in a for loop using this insert function.
I am querying first to check whether there is a similar resource in the database already. If so we don't need to recreate it.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    !function(i){
        addResource("url", "type", ...)
    }(i) // for local variable with callback
}
function addResource(url, type, callback){
    getResource({"url":url}, function(tx, result){
        console.log(result.rows.length, result.rows.length===1);
        if(result.rows.length===0){ //didn't exist yet -> create it && return id
            insertResource(url, type, function(tx, r){
                callback(r.insertId);
            });
        } else if(result.rows.length===1){ //already exist -> return id
            callback(result.rows.item(0).id);
        } else { //should not happen -> error
            console.error("addResource: Non unique identifier");
        }
    });
}
function insertResource(url, type, callback){
    var query = "INSERT INTO resource(url, type) VALUES (?, ?);";
    insert(query, [url, type], callback);
}
```

However, when i run this code, the same resource gets added 20 times instead of only once. I suspect that the delay on the execution of the callbacks makes it so that all the "===0" checks pass before any of them are created.
So is there maybe a way to stop this from happening? When i put constraints on the database the code just stops running when the constraint is violated, which i don't want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect that the delay on the execution of the callbacks makes it so that all the "===0" checks pass before any of them are created.

Yeah. You have a race condition going between each round by mixing a synchronous `for` loop with asynchronous `getResource()` and `insert()`.

The loop starts all 20 rounds in parallel, which are all looking for duplicates at the same time, before any have actually been inserted. They all find their result set empty, so they each insert.

You'll probably want to use an asynchronous iterator, such as [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async)'s [`timesSeries()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#times), so each round is delayed until those before it have completed.

```
async.timesSeries(20, function (i, done) {
    addResource("url", "type", function (id) {
        // ...
        done(null);
    });
});
```

Comment: This looked promising but unfortunately resulted in the same effect. when i use the async method i still end up creating 20 of the same rows in my database.

Comment: No you are correct, i was messing up.. Thanks a bunch.. it sorta works now.. <3